# Commit issue in Execute sql task Pentaho spoon 7

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I have once execute SQL task in my KTR and its has multiple Insert statement. I want to understand how transaction control work here. Do I need COMMIT after every Insert or only at end.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to commit while using 'execute SQL' step in Spoon. The commit happens automatically.